# How to encrypt exFAT on external drive?

Tags: filesystem, encryption, exfat

I have a lot of data on my external drive.
The file system is the exFAT.
I believe it is not possible to encrypt that filesystem with FileVault.

Do you know how (tool maybe) to encrypt exFAT on an external drive without changing filesystem?

Answer (score 4):

I confirm that drives that use the FAT or the exFAT file format can’t be encrypted using FileVault.

Therefore, if this can help, I suggest you to create two partitions of the device using two different file format.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer @Mattia. Sadly It is hard for me because I don't have additional disk to migrate 2T data to make partitioning.

Comment: This answer is correct. FileVault disk encryption requires your disk to be GPT (GUID partition table) and the volume type to be OSX extended (journaled JHFS+). I believe that an exFAT volume is not dynamically resizeable, so it would not be possible to create a small encrypted JHFS+ volume and progressively migrate files from one volume to the other whilst resizing both volumes (i.e. - growing the encrypted volume and shrinking the exFAT volume). You will need to borrow/buy more disk space. You could temporarily use cloud-based storage (eg BackBlaze) if your internet connection is very fast.

Comment: I did as you suggested. I borrowed the other disk made a copy and reformat to HFS+ with encryption. Thank you!

Comment: @HolySync I'm glad to know that.